# YOURLS - Not Redirecting to correct original URL after updating it

Tags: redirect, url-shortener, yourls

I installed YOURLS yesterday and it's amazing. There is one little quirk I can't seem to figure out. When I create a short URL but later change the original URL (where the short URL points to) it doesn't cause your browser to redirect to the new original URL if you previously clicked on the short URL before the update.

Example:

- Create a brand new short URL with the destination cnn.com
- Test the short URL - it will go to cnn.com
- Change the original URL on the same short URL to now point to cnet.com
- Click on the same short URL again, and it still went to cnn.com

Now, if I go into incognito mode or a different browser to go to that short URL after changing it, it works fine. It's almost as if the user's browser "saves" where the initial link goes and doesn't check to see if the short URL has changed its destination.

Is there a way to always have a web browser that has previously clicked on the link to always check the orignal URL in case it has changed?

Thank you!

Dan

Answer (score 2):

Simple, clear your browser cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the browser saves the data - that's what they're supposed to do.

You need to set the expiration times on... well, everything.